# Unity3D - HC-05 bluetooth module connected to Arduino Uno: Reads always timeout

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bluetooth, serial-port

I am trying to use an HC-05 module connected to an Arduino Uno to wirelessly send data from an IMU as input to a Unity3D simulation. I have confirmed that the module works using PuTTY and it sends and receives properly. When i connect in unity and try to read from the HC-05, it always times out. I've tried to change the `sp.ReadLine()` to `sp.Read()` to see if it was just missing the newline character but no difference.

This is the Unity code

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO.Ports;`

using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
private Rigidbody rb;
Vector3 origin,newPos;
SerialPort sp;
string text;
int trials = 0;
float speed;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    origin = rb.position;
    sp = new SerialPort("\\\\.\\COM4", 9600);
    if (!sp.IsOpen)
    {
        print("Opening COM4, baud 9600");
        sp.Open();
        sp.ReadTimeout = 100;
        sp.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        if (sp.IsOpen) { print("Open"); }

    }
}

void reset()
{
    rb.position = origin;
}

void Update()
{
    string data;

    float r = Input.GetAxis("Cancel");
    Vector3 toPos=new Vector3();

    if (!sp.IsOpen)
    {   trials++;
        sp.Open();
        print(trials);
    }
    if (r != 0.0f)
    {
        reset();
    }


    if (sp.IsOpen)
    {
        //print("SP is OPEN");
        data = sp.ReadLine();
        sp.BaseStream.Flush();

        //if (data != null) {
            //print("data recieved");
            text = data.ToString();
            //float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
            //toPos.Set(data[6],data[7],data[8]);
            //rb.rotation.SetLookRotation(toPos,rb.position);
        //}

    }

}

private void OnGUI()
{
    text=GUI.TextField(new Rect(10, 10, 200, 20), text);
}
```

This is the Arduino code

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>// import the serial library
#include <Wire.h>//I2C library

enum Ascale {
  AFS_2G = 0,
  AFS_4G,
  AFS_8G,
  AFS_16G
};

enum Gscale {
  GFS_250DPS = 0,
  GFS_500DPS,
  GFS_1000DPS,
  GFS_2000DPS
};

enum Mscale {
  MFS_14BITS = 0,
  MFS_16BITS
};


uint8_t Gscale = GFS_250DPS;
uint8_t Ascale = AFS_2G;
uint8_t Mscale = MFS_16BITS;
uint8_t Mmode = 0x02;
float aRes, gRes, mRes;

int intPin = 12;
int myLed = 13;

int16_t accelCount[3];
int16_t gyroCount[3];
int16_t magCount[3];

int16_t tempCount; 
float temperature; 
float SelfTest[6];


SoftwareSerial ser(10, 11); // RX, TX
int BluetoothData; // the data given from Computer
float AccelResult;
float AccelScale=16384;
float GyroResult;
float GyroScale=32.8;
float AltResult;
bool isInit=false;

void writeTo(byte device, byte toAddress, byte val) {
  Wire.beginTransmission(device);
  Wire.write(toAddress);
  Wire.write(val);
  Wire.endTransmission();
}

void readFrom(byte device, byte fromAddress, int num, byte result[]) {
  Wire.beginTransmission(device);
  Wire.write(fromAddress);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom((int)device, num);
  int i = 0;
  while (Wire.available()) {
    result[i] = Wire.read();
    i++;
  }
}

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  initMPU9250();
  float magCalibration[3];
  initAK8963(magCalibration);
  ser.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (ser.available()){
    if(ser.read()=='b'){
    //ser.println("hello");
    getData();
    }
}
delay(50);// prepare for next data ...
}

void getData(){

    readAccelData(accelCount);
    ser.println("ACCEL DATA------------------");
    ser.print("  X-Axis Accel "); ser.println(accelCount[0]);
    ser.print("  Y-Axis Accel "); ser.println(accelCount[1]);
    ser.print("  Z-Axis Accel "); ser.println(accelCount[2]);

    readGyroData(gyroCount);
    ser.println("GYRO DATA-------------------");
    ser.print("  X-Axis Gyro "); ser.println(gyroCount[0]);
    ser.print("  Y-Axis Gyro "); ser.println(gyroCount[1]);
    ser.print("  Z-Axis Gyro "); ser.println(gyroCount[2]);

    readMagData(magCount);
    ser.println("MAG DATA--------------------");
    ser.print("  X-Axis Mag "); ser.println(magCount[0]);
    ser.print("  Y-Axis Mag "); ser.println(magCount[1]);
    ser.print("  Z-Axis Mag "); ser.println(magCount[2]);
    ser.println("TEMP DATA-------------------");
    tempCount=readTempData();
    ser.print("  Temp "); ser.println(tempCount);
    ser.println("");
}
```

This the output from PuTTY

```
ACCEL DATA------------------
  X-Axis Accel -9665
  Y-Axis Accel -11690
  Z-Axis Accel -3847
GYRO DATA-------------------
  X-Axis Gyro 177
  Y-Axis Gyro 181
  Z-Axis Gyro 130
MAG DATA--------------------
  X-Axis Mag 118
  Y-Axis Mag 418
  Z-Axis Mag -176
TEMP DATA-------------------
  Temp 1050
```

This is the exception

```
TimeoutException: The operation has timed-out.
System.IO.Ports.WinSerialStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.read_byte ()
System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.ReadTo (System.String value)
System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.ReadLine ()
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.Ports.SerialPort:ReadLine ()
PlayerController.Update () (at Assets/PlayerController.cs:59)
```

I apologize for the lengthy post and am grateful for any and all help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yea, I solved it. It was a stupid mistake. Go figure.
My arduino was waiting for me to send 'b' before sending the data and i removed the line that did that while trying to correct a different error. hence the timeout as there was no data to read.